# Explicit Implementation of Marker C# Interfaces

Tags: c#

Imagine a situation where two [marker interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern) `A` and `B` guard single `Base` interface:

```
interface Base
{
    void Hello();
}

interface A: Base
{

}

interface B: Base
{

}
```

Is there a way to define class `C` that [implements both](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation) `A` and `B` while providing marker interface specific `Hello` implementations? Note that `Base`, `A` and `B` interfaces are declared in an external library so I could not modify it.

If I do this

```
class C: A, B
{
    void A.Hello() =>
        Console.Out.WriteLine("A");

    void B.Hello() =>
        Console.Out.WriteLine("B");
}
```

...it results in [CS0539](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0539?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0539)) compiler error:

> member in explicit interface declaration is not a member of interface.

Comment: Tell me, if I had this code `Base obj = new C(); obj.Hello();` - can you tell me which `Hello` would be called if you could do what you're asking?

Comment: If you want to read more about it: What Enigmativity describes is called the [Diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem) in literature. If I remember correctly, the Java and .NET designers decided not to allow multiple inheritance to avoid this issue.

Comment: @Enigmativity If [C3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization) (or alike) linearization was used, I'd expect `A`'s `Hello`. But @Heinzi has a point that this simply does not apply to C# world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible in C# without modifying the interfaces. The only explicit interface implementation that is possible is `Base.Hello`:

```cs
class C: A, B
{
    void Base.Hello() =>
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Base");
}
```